# Reading and closing files in Haskell

Tags: xml, haskell, file-io

I am a beginner in Haskell and currently I am trying to parse a list of xml files.

To parse an xml file from a given filename I am using the following function

```
searchXML :: String -> IO News
searchXML file = do
    rsp <- readFile file
    let tags = parseTags rsp 
    return News { author   = get_val "createdBy" tags,
                  headline = get_val "headline" tags,
                  content  =  get_val "text" tags}
    where 
        extr a b c = drop 1 $ takeWhile (~/= TagClose a) $
                     dropWhile (~/= TagOpen a b) c
        get a b = extr "value" [] $ extr "property" [("name",a)] b
        get_val a b = fromTagText $ (get a b) !! 0
```

which is called for a list of xml files

```
searchForKW :: String -> IO [News]
searchForKW keyword = do
xmlList <- simpleFind (\p -> takeExtension p == ".xml") "."
xml <- mapM searchXML xmlList
return $ filter (kwInNews keyword) xml
where
    kwInNews :: String -> News -> Bool
    kwInNews keyword (News {author=a,headline=b,content=c}) = isInfixOf keyword c
```

however this results in an `openFile: resource exhausted (Too many open files)` error. So I am thinking that the files are opened for reading but not closed. How can I fix this?

PS: Any further refactoring hints are very welcome.

Comment: the problem is that you read the files *lazy* - better use something like http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:readFile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readFile` function is notorious for this. It pretends to read the entire file into one giant string, but it doesn't. Just just opens the file for reading and returns instantly. The file only ever gets closed when either:

- your program inspects the very last character of the string
- your program drops all references to the result, and the garbage collector runs

Trouble is, Haskell is lazy. It might *look* like your code processes the entire string immediately, but actually it depends on what you do with the result of that processing. This kind of thing can be quite tricky to figure out. The whole *point* of Haskell is that it shouldn't matter when your code actually gets executed — but here we are, needing code to execute at a particular moment, because a real-world observable thing only happens when the code is run.

Really, `readFile` is great for quickly checking that some small example works how you expect. As soon as you want control over when files get opened / closed or you want high performance (i.e., processing a *large* XML file), you'll want to avoid `readFile`.

If you know the files are small / performance is not critical, you could just manually `openFile`, `hGetLine` and `hClose`. That way you know exactly when the file closes, because you're closing it. You may also want to look at the ByteString library; there is a function similar to `readFile`, which returns a strict ByteString (in other words, it *really* loads the entire file at once). The `ByteString` type is also quite a lot more efficient than the `String` type (but more fiddly to use).

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of @MathematicalOrchid I am using `readFile` from Data.ByteString and the `Data.ByteString.Char8.unpack` function to convert the ByteString in to a String

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as Str 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Char8

searchXML :: String -> IO News
searchXML file = do
    rsp <- Str.readFile file
    let get a = getVal a $ parseTags $ Char8.unpack rsp 
        auth  = get "createdBy"
        headl = get "headline"
        cont  = get "text"
    return News {author = auth, headline = headl, content = cont}
    where 
          extract tag attr = (drop 1) . (takeWhile (~/= TagClose tag))
                             . dropWhile (~/= TagOpen tag attr)
          getVal attr      = (fromTagText . safeHead . extract "value" []) 
                             . extract "property" [("name", attr)]
          safeHead (x:xs)  = x 
          safeHead []      = TagText " "
```

Comment: Why are you converting it to a `String`? `String` is almost always wrong, as it turns out. If you use `{-# OverloadedStrings #-}` you can use `ByteString` literals, and `ByteString` provides lots of different stringy operations for you to use to process them.

Comment: But as for XML, there are packages for doing that properly.